# I can't seem to figure out why a datagridview is not populating. (Also, a weird error came up when tracing)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm attempting to pull data from a SQLite database, and the first DGV loads just fine, but the second doesn't. When debugging, I get this:

> -Current 'this.specListing.Current' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'  object {System.IndexOutOfRangeException}

this.specListing is a BindingSource. The more specific error is "Index -1 does not have a value", and there are 2 items (Count: 2)

The code is:

```
public frmClassEditor()
{
    //start listing
    InitializeComponent();
    this.clsList = new List<SQLiteDataPair>();
    this.specList = new List<pilotSpec>();

    //create binding sources
    this.clsListing = new BindingSource();
    this.specListing = new BindingSource();

    //updated lags
    this.updatedSpec = true;

    //update listing
    updatePilotListing();
    this.clsListing.DataSource = this.clsList;
    this.specListing.DataSource = this.specList;

    dgvPilotListing.DataSource = this.clsListing;
    dgvPilotSpec.DataSource = this.specListing;

    refreshDGVPilot();
    }

private void refreshDGVSpec()
    {
    this.specListing.ResetBindings(false);
    if (dgvPilotSpec.Columns.Count > 0)
       {
            //do nothing right now
       }
    }

private void updatePilotSpecLst(SQLiteConnection conn, long classID)
{
    this.specList.Clear();
    SQLiteCommand getPilotSpec = conn.CreateCommand();
    getPilotSpec.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM classSpec WHERE classID = " + classID;
    SQLiteDataReader rdr = getPilotSpec.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
       this.specList.Add(new pilotSpec(rdr.GetInt64(0), rdr.GetString(1), txtClassName.Text, rdr.GetInt64(2)));
    }

    refreshDGVSpec();
    }
```

and pilotSpec is pretty simple:

```
public class pilotSpec
{
    public long pilotSpecID;
    public string pilotClassName;
    public string pilotSpecName;
    public long pilotSpecLevel;

    public pilotSpec(long id, string name, string className, long level)
    {
        this.pilotSpecID = id;
        this.pilotClassName = className;
        this.pilotSpecName = name;
        this.pilotSpecLevel = level;
    }
}
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: on what line your getting the error?

Comment: None of them. I only found out the datagrid one when I was going through the refreshDGVSpec() line by line, trying to find anything unusual. It appears at this.specListing.resetBindings(false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update the refresh grid method to this:

```
private void refreshDGVSpec()
{
    CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[dgvPilotSpec.DataSource];
    currencyManager.Refresh();
}
```

Edit: Your class members need to have public properties:

**Change** `public long pilotSpecID;` **to** `public long PilotSpecID { get; set; }`

Do the same for all public member variables.

Comment: Did so, afraid it didn't work. (I do note adding a second .Refresh() purges the error.) Columns and Rows on the dgvPilotSpec are still null.

Comment: Can you debug and see if any new elements are added to specList?

Comment: Both specList (the List) and specListing (the BindingSource) show both objects. Let me see where I can add a third and recall the refresh.

Comment: I have added a line that inserts into the db and list and the currencyManager, but it still leaves the dgv blank (edited to fix typo).

Comment: Can you change from List to BindingList and check.

Comment: I can, but it throws an error: no row can be added without having columns.

Comment: Its because the class has public members, need to be properties with getter/setter. Check my edit.

Comment: .. I feel like an absolute **moron**. That fixed it, and I am marking this answer as correct. Thanks!